# Regex formatting metacharacters

Tags: c#, regex

I need help to remove the characters in this line(the ^ & and \) and also the empty values in between them, im new to regex

```
1H|\^&|||ARCH^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||||||P|1|20150511083525
1D
```

it should be:

```
1H|ARCH|8.10|F3453010030|H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|P|20150511083525|1D
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `1H|ARCHITECT|8.10|F3453010030|H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|P|1|20150511083525|1D` ?

Comment: yes sorry that should be the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given string, you can use the following to replace those characters.

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w.]+", "|");
```

Comment: thank you, how about those empty values? can i just trim them or remove.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez: There are no empty values left after this: https://regex101.com/r/bJ7yA8/1

Answer (score 1):

```
[\^&\\|]+
```

Try this.Replace by `|`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/6

```
string strRegex = @"[\^&\\|]+";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"1H|\^&|||ARCHITECT^8.10^F3453010030^H1P1O1R1C1Q1L1|||||||P|1|20150511083525" + "\n" + @"1D";
string strReplace = @"|";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: wow, i wish i could choose this also an answer but hwnd got it first. i upvoted your answer.